# Reading Redis stream in Lua script

Tags: redis, lua

I am trying to read the following stream:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> xrevrange driver:70 + - count 1
1) 1) "1656531417451-0"
   2) 1) "field1"
      2) "value1"
      3) "isbusy"
      4) "true"
```

How can I read this stream in Lua script and reflect the field `isbusy` from the stream into the the local Lua variable `is_busy`?
I could not get my head around Lua collections.

```lua
local stream = KEYS[1]

local is_busy = false

local messages  = redis.call("XREVRANGE", stream, "+", "-", "COUNT", "1")

for _, message in ipairs(messages) do
  


end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the nested structure:

```
local id
for _, message in ipairs(messages) do
    for i, sub_msg in ipairs(message) do
        if i == 1 then
            id = sub_msg
        else
            -- parse attributes
            local i = 1
            while i < #sub_msg do
                local k = sub_msg[i]
                local v = sub_msg[i + 1]
                if k == "isbusy" then
                    is_busy = v
                end
                i = i + 2
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states the following:

> An entry is composed of a list of field-value pairs. The field-value
> pairs are stored in the same order they are given by the user.
> Commands that read the stream, such as XRANGE or XREAD, are guaranteed
> to return the fields and values exactly in the same order they were
> added by XADD.

Therefore, by always writing the fields in the same order, it becomes no longer necessary to iterate over all fields when searching for a specific field during a read operation. The field will be at the same index at which you wrote it.

Source: https://redis.io/commands/xadd/